# алгоритм с++, суммирование элементов в двумерном массиве

Tags: c++

в первой строке запрашиваем от пользователя размер массива
1 число сколько строк
2 число сколько колонок
например на фото 4х3
и суть программы в том, что бы 2 ряд (по индексу 1 ) искал для себя наибольшее число из соседей выше
например как на фото
число 10 ищет для себя соседнее число большее
т.е. число выше либо наискосок вверх
как на пример для числа 10 будут соседи 3 и 2
из этих двух чисел большее 3, значит 3+10
дальше идет к след числу в том же рядку(1 индекс ) 2 число будет 3 и для тройки соседями будут 3, 2 , 8 ну и наибольшее тут 8
и так же для двойки, наибольшее будет 8
потом пользователь вводит еще 1 ряд, и оно считает так же, только теперь 1 ряд это те числа посчитанные, а 2 ряд это числа введенные пользователем, ну и т.д

проблема вот в чем, программа хорошо считает для массива длиной в 3 числа
но уже при отклонении от этого числа начинается вакханалия, скорее что то напутал с индексами и циклом, но не могу понять что именно

ниже прикреплю фотографии примера работы программы и сам код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    cout.tie(nullptr);
    int n,m,max,sum, maxel,ind;
    cin>>n>>m;

    int **arr = new int *[2];

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int [m];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }

    }



    for(int h = 0; h<n-1; h++){
        for (int r =0; r<m; r++){
            cin>>arr[1][r];

        }
        for (int y = 0; y<m/2; y++) {

            if (arr[0][y] > arr[0][y+1]  )  {
                max = arr[0][y];

                sum = max + arr[0+1][y];
                arr[0+1][y] = sum;
                cout<<"1-1"<<endl;
            }
            if (arr[0][y] <= arr[0][y+1]  )  {
                max = arr[0][y+1];

                sum = max + arr[0+1][y];
                arr[0+1][y] = sum;
                cout<<"2-1"<<endl;
            }
            if (max  >= arr[0][y+2] ){
                if (arr[0][y] >= arr[0][0+1]){

                    arr[0][y] = max;
                    sum = max + arr[0+1][y+1];
                    arr[0+1][y+1] = sum;
                    cout<<"3-1"<<endl;
                }
                if (arr[0][y] < arr[0][0+1]){
                    arr[0][y+1] = max;
                    sum = max + arr[0+1][y+1];
                    arr[0+1][y+1] = sum;
                    cout<<"4-1"<<endl;
                }
            }
            if ( max  < arr[0][y+2]){
                max = arr[0][y+2];
                sum = max + arr[0+1][y+1];
                arr[0+1][y+1] = sum;
                cout<<"5-1"<<endl;
            }
            if (arr[0][y+1] <= arr[0][y+2]){
                max = arr[0][y+2];
                sum = max + arr[0+1][y+2];
                arr[0+1][y+2] = sum;
                cout<<"6-1"<<endl;
            }
            if (arr[0][y+1] > arr[0][y+2]){
                max = arr[0][y+1];
                sum = max + arr[0+1][y+2];
                arr[0+1][y+2] = sum;
                cout<<"7-1"<<endl;
            }

            for (int reverse=0; reverse<m; reverse++){
                arr[0][reverse] = arr[0+1][reverse];

            }


            }



    }

    maxel = arr[0][0];

    for ( ind = 0; ind<m; ind++){

        if(arr[0][ind]> maxel){

                maxel = arr[0][ind];
                //ind = ind;

        }

    }

    cout<<ind-1<<" "<<maxel<<"\n";



    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<m; j++){
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }


    //удаление массива

    for (int del = 0; del<2; del++) {
        delete[]arr[del];


    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пример работы почему-то вы так и не прикрепили.

Comment: добавил фотографию с примером

Comment: воспользуйтесь дебаггером